# R- How to randomly select from two different probabilities?

Tags: r, probability

I am looking to assign two different weighted probabilities (0.3 and 0.7). Each time (loop?) i want R to randomly select one of the two weighted probabilities. Then i need those data output in a dataframe.

I've tried a number of ways with no success. I am still a beginner.

Here is my noob code which doesn't work. I tried to sample the columns randomly.
Thanks.

```
roll_it<-c(1:100)
n70<- 1; p70<-7/10
n30<- 1; p30<-3/10

for( i in roll_it){ 
        result <- c(rbinom(n30, 1, p30), rbinom(n70, 1, p70))
        
        print(result)}

sample(result(1:2,), size=2, replace = F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your your goal correctly you don't need to use a loop at all. Just create two samples and then sample from that mixture distribution.

```
set.seed(1)

cc <- cbind(rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), rbinom(100, 1, 0.7))
colMeans(cc)
# [1] 0.32 0.70
sample(cc, 2)
# [1] 0 0
```

Comment: Exactly! This was a simple solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sample()`.

```
roll_it < -c(1:100)
n70<- 1
n30<- 1

probabilities <- c(0.3, 0.7)
for(i in roll_it){ 
    result <- rbinom(x = n30, size = 1, prob = sample(probabilities, 1))
    print(result)
}
```

May I add, I'm not sure why are you using n30 and n70. Could you just use one of them?

Comment: Right, i could use one of them; but this is a proof-of-concept thing to show differences in counterbalanced hidden variables. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you need me to edit the answer so that you use both of the variables?

Comment: That would be awesome!